# Pequeñas votaciones internas para características nuevas u otras discusiones

Tags: discusión

Ayer que gbianchi publico la idea de los banners (que por cierto me parece muy buena), me surgió una curiosidad.

Este tipo de publicaciones no son de todos los días, pero si que hay bastantes, en donde se presenta alguna decisión y en el espacio de respuestas hay dos respuestas: una que se indica a favor y otra que se indica en contra (ver imagen abajo). Usualmente, las respuestas obtienen votos, que significan si estamos a favor o en contra de la publicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, la curiosidad que me da es la siguiente. ¿Cuando sabemos si alguna característica esta aprobada o no? En el ejemplo que puse de los banners, hasta el momento la votación va 10 a 1. ¿Existe algún reglamento de tiempo? Por ejemplo: "después de 48 horas se revisan los votos", o quizas ¿un numero de votos? Por ejemplo: "después de que 50 usuarios voten, se daran los resultados".

¿Seria buena idea que el autor de la publicación pusiera sus propias reglas (de tiempo o de cantidad de votos)?

Comment: Kenny, generalmente el tiempo no es algo fijo. Dejamos pasar un tiempo _prudencial_ además que esperamos ver cierta participacion y si la diferencia de votos es considerable.  Tambien hay que tener en cuenta si se ha comentado a favor de una u otra creando debate. Un saludo

Comment: @fedorqui hahaha, ya lei la otra pregunta, en efecto es duplicada, gracias por aclararlo. Pero mi risa viene de que, tu pregunta se quedo en el limbo, tratando de resolver el limbo. Supongo que nunca se podra resolver. Gracias igual.

Comment: @KennyBarrera son las muñecas rusas del Meta: una pregunta Meta para decidir cómo gestionar las preguntas sobre Meta. Veamos cuántos niveles podemos llegar a acumular :D

Comment: @fedorqui un par mas en el proximo año diria yo. Es posible para un moderador diamantado editar el Centro de Ayuda? Porque si asi fuera, quizas alguien podria ponerle punto y final a esto y poner un tiempo especifico, quizas 20 dias?

Comment: Talvez @lois6b quisiera hacerlo.

Comment: @KennyBarrera es difícil determinar, pues en los límites habita la picaresca. Yo creo que lo importante es marcar como [meta-tag:destacado], dar tiempo y solamente proponer votaciones binarias como último recurso: muchas veces hay opciones intermedias que acaban teniendo mejor acogida.